# Trotter decomposition from Baker-Hausdorff

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lie-algebras

The general Baker-Hausdorff formula is :

\begin{equation}
e^{(\hat{A} +\hat{B})t} = e^{t\hat{A}} e^{t\hat{B}} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}[\hat{A},\hat{B}]} e^{t\hat{B}} e^{\frac{t^3}{6}(2[\hat{B},[\hat{A},\hat{B}]] + [\hat{A},[\hat{A},\hat{B}]])} ...
\end{equation}

It should be easy to find the Trotter decomposition:

\begin{equation}
e^{(\hat{A} +\hat{B})t} = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(  e^{\frac{\hat{A}t}{n}} e^{\frac{\hat{B}t}{n}}   \right)^n 
\end{equation}

I tried to express the exponential as it's Taylor expansion but I get nowhere. Do you have any idea how to start the derivation. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use the Baker-Hausdorff formula, just use the definition of an exponentiated operator   $e^H  = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1+\frac{H}{n} \right)^n $

\begin{equation}
e^{(\hat{A} +\hat{B})t} = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1+\frac{(\hat{A}+\hat{B})t}{n} \right)^n 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( (1+\frac{\hat{A}t}{n}) (1+\frac{\hat{B}t}{n})\right)^n 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(  e^{\frac{\hat{A}t}{n}} e^{\frac{\hat{B}t}{n}}   \right)^n 
\end{equation}

Comment: I have a problem with your solution, from the first to the second line you omit the term -ABt²/n² and from the second to the third you don't use properly the definition.

Comment: @Maxime:  1) $(1+\frac{At}{n}+\frac{Bt}{n}) =(1+\frac{At}{n}) (1+\frac{Bt}{n})$ because $(\frac{t}{n})^2<<(\frac{t}{n})$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$  and 2) Only the first term in line 3 for the expansion of the exponentials is significant for the same reason as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Then we would have the result as an approximation and not as an equality. I thought it was possible to get the Trotter decomposition without any approximation starting from the Baker-Hausdorff formula as stated in the literature, the approximation should only be necessary for a finite n.

Comment: This is a correct derivation. To handle the $1/n^2$ terms more "rigorously", let $(1 + H/n)^n = \exp[n \log(1 + H/n)]$ and use all your standard rules for taking limits.